# How can one claim they proved $φ$ or $¬φ$ without knowing which?

Tags: logic

I've been told True Arithmetic is syntactically complete(either $φ$ or $¬φ$ is provable for every $φ$), yet one cannot decide which of the two. This makes no sense to me. How can one say they proved either $φ $ or $¬φ$, without knowing which?

Comment: You probably believe that the twin prime conjecture is either true or false. So if you take "all true facts about $\mathbb{N}$" as your axioms, then you know that either the twin prime conjecture or its negation is an axiom! So you know you can prove one of them (with a very short proof too), but you have no idea which one you can prove!

Comment: 'provable' is not the same as 'proved'

Comment: @Bram28 Thanks, I now see where I misunderstood.

Comment: This is actually exactly the sort of thing that led Brouwer to reject the law of the excluded middle! See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/ .